# Get cookie on first load

Tags: javascript, cookies

So I created this new thread for this one since it was so bad explained, but was told to edit this one:

**New Text**

I need to receive a user_id from a external website. I only need to receive this if the user come to site A from site B. So when he does that I then save that user_id in a cookie, that part is working fine. But I also need to get the value of the cookie when he first land on the page, so let me try to explain how I have done this:

First I look at if user is coming from another domain:

```
var ownDomain = location.hostname,
    referrerDomain = document.referrer.split('/')[2],
    author = '';

if ( ownDomain != referrerDomain) {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = '//javascript.mamp/json/?callback=setAuthorCookie';
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

If he does that, then we insert a javascript which calls the callback `setAuthorCookie()`, which looks like this:

```
function setAuthorCookie( data ) {
  var exdate = new Date(),
      exdays = 1,
      value = data['userId'],
      cookie = 'partnerOptimizerId',
      exdate = new Date();

   author = value;

   exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
   var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
   document.cookie=cookie + "=" + c_value;
}
```

Now as you can see I set the author value inside that function,  so I should be able to console.log out the value of author and get the correct value:

```
console.log( author )
```

I return nothing, which is kind of where Im stuck right now. I guess it is because that some how `setAutorCookie` runs after I `console.log( author )`, but I was hoping someone could help me on this, is it because `author` is a local variable in `setAuthorCookie` ?

**After some testing I can see that setAuthorCookie runs after the last console.log() and that is why it is empty but can somebody help with how I change that ?**

Comment: Where is `setAuthorCookie` called? As far as I can see, it's never used. I wouldn't alter variables outside the scope of functions like this either, it's bound to cause some confusion.

Answer (score 2):

You're only returning something from `getCookie()` under certain conditions:

```
  if (x==cookie)
  {
    return unescape(y);
  }
```

So if x != cookie, your function does not have  a return. Therefore when you say `var author = getCookie( 'partnerOptimizerId' );`, but `getCookie()` doesn't return anything, `author` will be undefined.

Comment: Ok, but what if I then do like this `// var author = getCookie( 'partnerOptimizerId' );` then I should set the author in the `setAuthorCookie()` function, right ? But then the console.log only output a empty string.